# Foreign key in design class diagrams

Tags: mysql, database, class-diagram, object-oriented-analysis

My question is whether Foreign keys are supposed to be represented in a design class diagram?

Suppose I have 2 classes

```
employee
----------
empId
name
jobId //fk

Job
-------
jobId
jobName
```

I'm supposed to develop the my software using object oriented techniques; hence I'm required to use UML diagrams to model my system.

I have seen people do the following way to link the 2 classes together:

They create they 2 classes with their initial attributes and then they use an object attribute inside another class.
In the example that I have shown above, the class diagram will be as follows:

```
employee
--------
empId:Int
name:String
job:job //a job object data type

job
-------
jobId:Int
jobName:String
```

I want to know whether this is a proper approach to this problem

Now when implementing my application using a database.. (I'm using mysql with Java on eclipse)
How are the objects/data be stored? Is it going to be storing objects (as I explained on the example) or using foreign key variables.. Like the conventional way?

I'll be very grateful if ever I have my doubts clarified! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Foreign key is concept of database, and in database ER Diagram is used.
Class diagrams can have only members and member funtions with optional modifiers.
And the second option is the correct way to denote it in class diagram.

```
employee
--------
empId:Int
name:String
job:job //a job object data type

job
-------
jobId:Int
jobName:String
```

The above class diagram explains there are 2 classes job with jobId and jobName as members AND Employee with empId,name and job(class) as members.

Comment: However, if I have to use a database to implement my classes and store the objects created when thr application is used, how must I approach this problem?